# Solr - 0 results when filtering by TrieDateField

Tags: solr

I have a Solr (7.2) index with the following field:

```
Field: __smallupdateddate_tdt
Field-Type:org.apache.solr.schema.TrieDateField
Docs:424,202
```

In Schema Browser, if I click on any result in the Top-Terms list:

[image]

I get 0 results.

[image]

I can't seem to filter on this date field at all. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an artifact of the way Trie fields are indexed. As the doc says:

> For each number being added to this field, multiple terms are
>   generated as per the algorithm described in the above link.

Notice the *multiple* there. So the terms you see in that list, don't necesarily mean there is a doc with it really.

The reason to do this is for better perf.